# int.__mul__ , executes 2X slower than operator.mul

Tags: python, c

If you look at the following timings:

```
C:\Users\Henry>python -m timeit -s "mul = int.__mul__" "reduce(mul,range(10000))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 908 usec per loop

C:\Users\Henry>python -m timeit -s "from operator import mul" "reduce(mul,range(10000))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 410 usec per loop
```

There is a significant difference in execution speed between

`reduce(int.__mul__,range(10000))` and `reduce(mul,range(10000))` with the latter being faster.

using the `dis` module to look at what was happening:

Using `int.__mul__` method:

```
C:\Users\Henry>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mul = int.__mul__
>>> def test():
...     mul(1,2)
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (mul)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

And the operator `mul` method

```
C:\Users\Henry>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from operator import mul
>>> def test():
...     mul(1,2)
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (mul)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

They appear the same, so why is there a difference in execution speed? I am referring to the CPython implementation of Python

---

The same happens on python3:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'mul=int.__mul__;from functools import reduce' 'reduce(mul, range(10000))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from operator import mul;from functools import reduce' 'reduce(mul, range(10000))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 643 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'mul=lambda x,y:x*y;from functools import reduce' 'reduce(mul, range(10000))'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 msec per loop
```

Comment: You are looking at the bytecode disassembly of `test()` and it just calls `mul`, hence it's the same in both cases. It's the two implementations of `mul` that probably differ.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, I didn't that it was only disassembling test. I suppose that makes a lot more sense. I'll go looking into how these were implemented some more then.

Comment: Are you using python two? The problem might be that int's mul will overflow and call long's mul  while operator avoid this extra calls.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, Python 2.7.4

Comment: I thought the problem was the conversions between `int` and `long`, but even in python3 the results are the same, with `operator.mul` being twice as fast as `int.__mul__`. But, from the sources, it's pretty clear that both end up calling `PyNumber_Multiply`. The only thing that I can think of is that the `operator` module avoids a bit of overhead of the interpreter, but still 2x is simply too much faster.

Comment: What source are you looking at, I've looked at http://www6.uniovi.es/python/dev/src/c/html/operator_8c-source.html so far.

Comment: Using `profile.run('reduce(mul, range(10000))')` shows even strangier results: both with `int.__mul__` and `operator.mul` only 5 function calls are executed(which means something is optimized). Using `mul=lambda x,y:x*y` executes about `10k` function calls(shouldn't be optimized) but the time taken is the same as with `int.__mul__`.

Comment: @HennyH I'm quite amused by your question. Also because I cannot find any trace of optimizations in the code for `reduce`/`operator.mul` or whatever. I really don't see any reason why `reduce(operator.mul, X)` does only one function call when `reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, X)` does a call for each element. The `reduce` call simply uses `PyEval_CallObject` on each pair, without checking what the function called is; and this calls `PyObject_Call` without special-casing anything.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't believe that's related to this question at all (you should probably edit it out) the function calls seem to be the ones called by Python itself and not by a function in `C` calling a function in `C`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`int.__mul__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/intobject.c#l1374) is a slot wrapper, namely, a [PyWrapperDescrObject](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/descrobject.c#l574), while [`operator.mul`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Modules/operator.c#l91) is a buit-in function.
I think the opposite execution speed is caused by this difference.

```
>>> int.__mul__
<slot wrapper '__mul__' of 'int' objects>
>>> operator.mul
<built-in function mul>
```

When we call a [PyWrapperDescrObject](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/descrobject.c#l574), [`wrapperdescr_call`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/descrobject.c#l306) is called.

```
static PyObject *
wrapperdescr_call(PyWrapperDescrObject *descr, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    Py_ssize_t argc;
    PyObject *self, *func, *result;

    /* Make sure that the first argument is acceptable as 'self' */
    assert(PyTuple_Check(args));
    argc = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args);
    if (argc d_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    self = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0);
    if (!_PyObject_RealIsSubclass((PyObject *)Py_TYPE(self),
                                  (PyObject *)(descr->d_type))) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "descriptor '%.200s' "
                     "requires a '%.100s' object "
                     "but received a '%.100s'",
                     descr_name((PyDescrObject *)descr),
                     descr->d_type->tp_name,
                     self->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    func = PyWrapper_New((PyObject *)descr, self);
    if (func == NULL)
        return NULL;
    args = PyTuple_GetSlice(args, 1, argc);
    if (args == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(func);
        return NULL;
    }
    result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(func, args, kwds);
    Py_DECREF(args);
    Py_DECREF(func);
    return result;
}
```

Let us look at what we found!

```
func = PyWrapper_New((PyObject *)descr, self);
```

A new PyWrapper object has been constructed. It would slow down the execution speed significantly.
Sometimes, it takes more time to create a new object than to run a simple function.
Thus, it is not surprised that `int.__mul__` is slower than `operator.mul`.